dax measure percentage of cost
i am trying to get the cost percentage over the revenue, these are my fact and dims table


i currently have three measures to get the total cost, the revenue and the cost percentage,
Total_Cost = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_tablef[Value]),
    fact_table[Cost Element Id] IN VALUES(dims_table[Cost Element Id]),
    FILTER(
        fact_table,
        fact_table[Cost Element Id] IN VALUES(dims_table[Cost Element Id])

Revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_table[Value]),
    fact_table[Cost Element Id] = "Revenue"
)

Percentage = DIVIDE([Total_Cost],[Revenue],0)

the problem is the percentage shows just fine when its the grand total cost, but when i select the cost category or the cost element the percentage shows 0.
are there any issues with my calculation, are there any solution to fix this?
thanks!
Edit:
Sample Data (i'll be using whole numbers for the sake of simple calculation)
(only including the columns that are used)



Workcell
Cost Element Id
Cost Element Name
Value




Customer 1
Revenue
Revenue
1000


Customer 1
00002
Pedals
200


Customer 1
00003
Headlights
100






Cost Category
Cost Element Id
Cost Element Name




Components
00002
Pedals


Components
00003
Headlights



using the measures above, the desired output would be
percentage = 30% no slicer applied, total of all cost (this works fine)
percentage = 30% workcell slicer applied(Customer 1 selected) (this also works fine)
percentage = 30% cost category slicer applied (Components selected) this does not work, shows 0%
percentage = 10% cost element id slicer applied (00003 selected)
this also doesn't work, shows 0%

Do you have any relationships between the two tables? What fields/columns are you using in your Matrix?

@SamNseir yes one to many on cost element id, not too sure what you mean by matrix, do you mean what field/column am i visualizing? If so, its the percentage

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

@Ryan hi please check the latest edit

Since you have a relationship between the two, your Revenue measure is returning null when the dims_table is filtered. You will need to "remove" the relationship with either of these two options:
Using REMOVEFILTERS:
Revenue = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_table[Value]),
    fact_table[Cost Element Id] = "Revenue",
    REMOVEFILTERS(dims_table)
  )

Using CROSSFILTER:
Revenue = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_table[Value]),
    fact_table[Cost Element Id] = "Revenue",
    CROSSFILTER(dims_table[Cost Element Id], fact_table[Cost Element Id], None)
  )


interesting, i found that using ALL(dimstable) also achieve this, thanks for you help!
